# remove last 14 digits from string and a underscore, if there are 14 digits

Tags: regex, bash

I have a string like this:

`data-c(huk24-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(huk24)_20130620200658`

where the timestamp with 14 digits and the underscore should be removed. So it should look like this:

`data-c(huk24-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(huk24)`

How can I achieve this in a bash script? Note that removing should only happen, when there really is an underscore and 14 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sed:

```
echo $str | sed 's/_[0-9]\{14\}$//'
```

OR

```
echo ${str%_[0-9]*}
```

Comment: +1 for readability ! but please use quotes: `echo "$str" | sed  's/_[0-9]\{14\}$//'`  #the example have str containing ; and other characters

Answer (score 4):

Use parameter expansion:

```
string=${string%_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
```

Comment: Or funnier (and shorter): `printf -v re '%14s'; string=${string%_${re// /[[:digit:]]}}`

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk --re-interval -F_ '{$NF~/^[0-9]{14}$/?NF--:NF}1' <<< $var
```

Comment: why not just `$ awk -F_ '{print $1}' <<< $var` since there's only one underscore in the teststring.

Comment: @FredrikPihl Yep, but OP's requirement was to eliminate the the second part ONLY IF it was a digit with length of 14.

Comment: yeah, I saw that, bad example string so I thought I'd be obnoxious :-)

Comment: @FredrikPihl inga problem, det gör inget!! ;)

Comment: Svenska?!? Nu blev jag nyfiken!

Comment: ah, a very good translation if I might say so. Florida + Jaypal didn't sound too swedish but you never know :-) +1 for GT

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
perl -plE 's/_\d{14}$//' < input > output
```

e.g

```
echo 'data-c(huk24-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(huk24)_20130620200658' | perl -plE 's/_\d{14}$//'
```

produces:

```
data-c(huk24-small1);divider-bin-1.4.4;divider-conf-1.3.3-w(1,16);storage-bin-1.5.4;storage-conf-1.5.0-w(1);worker-bin-4.5.1;worker-conf-4.4.1-c(huk24)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `bash` regular expressions:

```
[[ $string =~ ^(.*)_[[:digit:]]{14}$ ]] && string=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```